# Action generating partial view realizes whole page must be replaced. How to redirect?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

This is a partially hypothetical question, as I don't actually need to do this at the moment.  I'm just anticipating that I might.

My MVC3 app has a page that has a partial view that is refreshed using MVC3 Ajax and `AjaxHelper.BeginForm()`.  It all works nicely.

But, it's possible for the action that generates the partial view to realize that rather than see a refresh of the partial view, the user needs to be sent to a completely different page.  In other words, rather than returning a `PartialViewResult`, the action method needs to return a `RedirectResult` or a regular `View`.

This, as you no doubt know, won't work:  attempts to return a `RedirectResult` when the signature calls for a `PartialViewResult` won't compile.

So how can this be accomplished?  Let's say for the sake of argument that the necessary decision can only be made server-side and only after the information in the partial view is posted back to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, define your method to return an `ActionResult`, which will allow you to return either a `PartialViewResult` or `RedirectResult`, as needed.

Second, supply an [`OnFailure`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxoptions.onfailure.aspx) callback function in your `BeginForm()` method call. If the result of the AJAX call is not an HTTP 200, the `OnFailure` callback will be run, which you can then use to parse the redirect response and perform the redirect.

Comment: Thank you!  Since posting, I've also read the suggestion of a separate Ajax call to determine what needs to be returned, followed by an Ajax call or redirect, as needed.

Comment: That would be preferrable, if you can work it into your design; it would eliminate the simplicity of a single BeginForm() call in your View but it would probably be much easier to understand if you came back 6 months later to fix a bug.